# Go HTTP Client not returning cookies

Tags: http, cookies, go

I am using go http client to make get requests and the client has been initialised with a cookiejar however the response cookie array is empty. Has anyone got any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
 jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s.http_client = &http.Client{Jar: jar}

   resp, _ := s.http_client.Get(s.url)
```

`fmt.Println(resp.Cookies())` returns an empty array although I can see cookies returned in firefox.

Comment: Make sure the cookies sent are valid cookies. Go might be a bit stricter than Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a [`cookiejar`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CookieJar), and you can use it as seen in "[how to follow location with cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18414212/6309)":

```
jar, err := cookiejar.New(&options)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
client := http.Client{Jar: jar}  // <============
resp, err := client.Get("http://dubbelboer.com/302cookie.php")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
resp.Body.Close()
```

([introduced with Go1.1 as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386573/6309))

An [`http.Client`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) struct has:

```
    // Jar specifies the cookie jar.
    // If Jar is nil, cookies are not sent in requests and ignored
    // in responses.
    Jar CookieJar
```

---

As [3of3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4130971/3of3) mentions, you don't need a cookiejar to **[fetch a cookie](https://github.com/astaxie/build-web-application-with-golang/blob/master/en/eBook/06.1.md#fetch-cookies-in-go)**:

```
for _, cookie := range r.Cookies() {
    fmt.Fprint(w, cookie.Name)
}
```

Check if the cookiejar is still empty *after* having read the full response body.

Comment: I do make use of the cookiejar as in the updated code preview but still get an empty array of cookies.

Comment: @cobie is it still empty *after* having read the response body? (I have edited the answer)

Comment: @cobie What does `resp.Cookies()` returns? (see end of edited answer)